# Does C++ allow default return types for functions?

Tags: c++, c

In C the following horror is valid:

```
myFunc()
{
  return 42;  // return type defaults to int.
}
```

But, what about in C++? I can't find a reference to it either way...

My compiler (Codegear C++Builder 2007) currently accepts it without warning, but I've had comments that this ***is*** an error in C++.

Comment: Which compiler is that? I've never encountered one that accepted it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It's *ill-formed* in C++. Meaning that it doesn't compile with a standard conforming compiler. Paragraph **7.1.5/4** in Annex C of the Standard explains the change "Banning implicit int".

Comment: For example if you compile with g++, be sure to have the `-W -Wall` flags to have the warning, or `-pedantic` to have it as an error.

Comment: you are walking encyclopedia of C/C++ standard :)

Comment: Ilya, i wish i were. i just own a copy of it hehe :)

Answer (score 9):

Implicit return types are valid in C89, but a lot of compilers warn about it.

They are not valid in C++, nor in C99.

Answer (score 5):

So, it's definitely 'ill formed' C++, but it seems many compilers accept it with a warning at best.

- Codegear C++Builder 2007: No error or warning at all
- G++: Requires -W -Wall to generate warning , or -pedantic to generate error (Piotr)
- MSVC 8: produces an error ([tfinniga](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331148/does-c-allow-default-return-types-for-functions#332312))
- others...?

Please add to/correct this list!

Answer (score 2):

This is not legal C++, but some compilers will accept it either silently or with a diagnostic.

Answer (score 1):

As posted, it is ill-formed.  MSVC 8 gives the following error:

```
error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
```