# How to round decimals in a double returned from a virtual function?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, c++14

/*
ok, I've been slaving over this for awhile to practice up on polymorphism. right now the compute pay implementation for hourly_worker looks like this

```
hourly_worker::compute_pay()
{

 tot_sal = hrs_wrk * hourly;  
 return tot_sal;
}
```

I want this to return $2000.00, but right now it only returns $2000, as the function is set to virtual return type instead of double. Is there anyway to get these decimal points in place without changing from a virtual function? Thanks guys

*/
right now this is my driver file:http://pastebin.com/hUYhxVEu
and tot_sal is a private double data member of Worker, and compute_pay is a public virtual function of Worker, inherited by every sub class. Please help lol. If you need/want to see anymore code just let me know. Also, here is the implementation file for hourly_worker. http://pastebin.com/CtjiZUCG Just to add, setprecision & fixed or showpoint don't do a damn thing to the return value.

Comment: Let's take a step back here: you do not **ever** use floating point values to represent a monetary value. How would you feel if your credit card statement, paycheck, etc. all contained errors from floating point imprecision?

Comment: The floating point was a mistype, it's actually a double, I changed that when I edited it. Anyway, I found my error, I needed compute_pay defined as a virtual double in worker.h instead of a straight virtual. I'm losing it over one word lmao. Thanks for replying though.

Comment: Doubles _are_ floating point.

Comment: "Virtual return type"? Virtual means that the function has polymorphic behavior. You still need a return type.

Comment: For classroom work this is OK, but no accountant will accept floating point here.

Comment: @JamesRoot I thought if you leave it just as virtual it just takes the implicit parameters and determines the return type from there at runtime. Is that incorrect?

Comment: You might be thinking of `auto`, which deduces a type at compile time. Although if the code compiled without a return type, I must be overlooking something. All that comes to mind is it defaulted to `int`, which I didn't think it was supposed to do ( `C++ does not support default int`).

Comment: @JamesRoot Ah but it did compile without a return type. This is the output without the return type https://i.imgur.com/lbR5XN8.png . This is it with a double return type https://i.imgur.com/ol125bt.png .

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Your function doesn't have `virtual` return type, it is `virtual`, which means when calling the function from a pointer or a reference, the function of the real type of the object will be called, not the one of the type of the pointer.

If you do not put a return type, some compilers non-conforming to C++ standard will use `int` as the default one (because this used to be the case in C). If you didn't truncate your code when copy/pasting it, it's probably your case. Therefore, your function returns `int`. If you want it to return a `double`, just change its signature:

```
virtual double hourly_worker::compute_day();
```

Now, of course, this will only be useful if either `hourly` and/or `hrs_wrk` is/are `double`. Otherwise, the result will be an `int` and adding .00 to it is just a matter of formatting the display.

As discussed in the comment, you may prefer fixed point arithmetic rather than floating point arithmetic for accounting. The idea is simple: use `int` (or `long int` to be able to handle billionaires) and multiply all values by 1000 (or more depending on the smallest amount you want to handle, I'm no specialist but I think tenth of cents is usually what is used).

Comment: No, the default return type is NOT `int`, nor has it ever been in the past. (There are other languages in which this may be or have been the case, but the question is about C++)

Comment: I didn't say it's standard C++. It doesn't compile with a standard conforming compiler but some compilers accept it as it was valid in C. If the posted code builds, it means the compiler used is one of them. But you're right, I'll precise it in the answer.

Comment: @MSalters: More details here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/331148/does-c-allow-default-return-types-for-functions

Comment: And more details about downvotes: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down
In particular: "If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it."