# Return a boolean in a function without a defined return type and save result in char compiles with no errors - why?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

Consider this program:

```
#include <iostream>

printStatement(std::string msg) {
    std::cout << msg;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    char w = printStatement("Hello World");
}
```

I'm using MinGW gcc to compile this code on Windows and to my surprise, the compiler compiles this without any objections, variable w apparently is set to '\001' after the function call. Several things are bothering me:

1. printStatement has no return type - apparently this is implicitly set to "int"?
2. But I'm returning a boolean - is there an implicit conversion to int happening?
3. I'm storing the result in char - is there again an implicit conversion happening from int to char?

I'm really questioning: Who is stopping me from shooting in my knees when developing C++ because apparently the compiler doesn't care.

Comment: The default return type was `int` in C (in C89, but not in C99), but it's normally illegal in C++. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331148/does-c-allow-default-return-types-for-functions

Comment: It doesn't compile with either gcc and clang. I don't know why MinGW lets it, but it mustn't allow compiling this code!

Answer (score 3):

Implicit return types are forbidden in all C++ standards. Some implementations may allow them to exist. This is forbidden by most industry coding standards. I'm not even going to look up how gcc handles this situation (whether it implies an `int` or `bool` return value), since you really shouldn't be doing it.

This is implementation defined behavior, but you shouldn't do it. Turn on all warnings `-Wall` and this should be warned against. You should have `-Wall` on by default anyway, and treat all warnings as errors unless you have a VERY good reason to allow the warning code in.

I realize I'm not answering your numbered questions, but the real answer to your questions is "none of that matters, don't do it, turn on your warnings".

Source: https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/c/DCL31-C.+Declare+identifiers+before+using+them

Comment: Actually, implicit return types never existed in any C++ standard.

Comment: Thanks for the correction. It's like the Mitch Hedberg joke: "I used to smoke weed. I still do, but I used to, too!"

Answer (score 3):

> 1. printStatement has no return type - apparently this is implicitly set to "int"?

Not in standard C++. Such declaration is ill-formed. But this used to be the case in the first C standard (about 30 years ago) and pre-standard C (even older). Some compilers support this as a language extension for backward compatibility.

---

> 2. But I'm returning a boolean - is there an implicit conversion to int happening?

Yes. `bool` is implicitly convertible to integer types.

---

> 3. I'm storing the result in char - is there again an implicit conversion happening from int to char?

Yes. Integer types are convertible to `char`.

---

> Who is stopping me from shooting in my knees when developing C++ because apparently the compiler doesn't care.

Your employer / lead developer might require you to not use language extensions, because they are a problem from portability perspective.

The compiler is required to diagnose the ill-formed declaration. Here is an example of a diagnostic message that it might produce:

> ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'printStatement' with no type [-fpermissive]

Reading the compiler output is essential for avoiding mistakes as a C++ programmer. If the compiler does not produce such diagnostic message, then it does not conform to the C++ standard. This would usually considered to be a bug in the compiler.

P.S. The conversion from `int` to `char` can be potentially dangerous (on most systems) because the value might not be representable in the target type. Your compiler has an option to warn about such potentially dangerous converions (`-Wconversion`).

Comment: To the last one: perhaps one of -Wall or -pedantic is needed to make it yell at you. I feel like this is GCC?

Comment: @HTNW The example was from GCC indeed. Neither -Wall nor -pedantic was needed. -pedantic is needed for GCC to be standard conforming regarding some other language extensions though (namely, VLA at least).

Answer (score 2):

> printStatement has no return type - apparently this is implicitly set to "int"?

this is illegal in C++

> But I'm returning a boolean - is there an implicit conversion to int happening?
>
> I'm storing the result in char - is there again an implicit conversion happening from int to char?

may be for both, but this is only relevant when specifying the compiler you use and tolerating the missing return type

---

If you do not want to declare the return type letting the compiler to do/decide for you, use `auto` :

```
#include <iostream>

auto printStatement(std::string msg) {
    std::cout << msg;
    return true;
}

int main() {
    char w = printStatement("Hello World");
}
```

and

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
c.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
c.cc:9:10: warning: unused variable ‘w’ [-Wunused-variable]
     char w = printStatement("Hello World");
          ^
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```

Adding for instance `return w;` at the end of *main* :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ g++ -Wall c.cc
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $
```