# What is meaning no declaration match error in my case?

Tags: c++

I described class in different files:

3DObjectDescription.h

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <NumCpp.hpp>
#include "MoveMatrix.h"

class Object3D
{
public:
    nc::NdArray<float> vertexes;

    nc::NdArray<float> faces;

    Object3D();

    void translation(float tX, float tY, float tZ);
    void rotate_x(float angle);
    void rotate_y(float angle);
    void rotate_z(float angle);
    void scale_(float scale_c);

};
```

3DObjectDescription.cpp

```
#include "3DObjectDescription.h"

Object3D::Object3D()
{
    vertexes = {{0,0,0,1}, {0,1,0,1}, {1,1,0,1}, {1,0,0,1},
                {0,0,1,1}, {0,1,1,1}, {1,1,1,1}, {1,0,1,1}};

    faces = {{0,1,2,3}, {4,5,6,7}, {0,4,5,1}, {2,3,7,6}, {1,2,6,5}, {0,3,7,4}};
}

Object3D::translation(float tX, float tY, float tZ)
{
    vertexes = nc::dot(vertexes, translate(tX, tY, tZ));
}

Object3D::rotate_x(float angle_)
{
    vertexes = nc::dot(vertexes, rotation_X(angle_));
}

Object3D::rotation_y(float angle_)
{
    vertexes = nc::dot(vertexes, rotation_Y(angle_));
}

Object3D::rotation_z(float angle)
{
    vertexes = nc::dot(vertexes, rotation_Z(angle_));
}

Object3D::scale_(float scale_c)
{
    vertexes = nc::dot(vertexes, scale(scale_c));
}
```

When I compiling it, I get errors:

**error: no declaration matches 'int Object3D::translation(float, float, float)'

error: no declaration matches 'int Object3D::rotate_x(float)'

error: no declaration matches 'int Object3D::rotation_y(float)'

error: no declaration matches 'int Object3D::rotation_z(float)'

error: no declaration matches 'int Object3D::scale_(float)'**

I dont know from where did the integer type come from, when I didnt declared it! And I had never met such error!

Comment: All those functions return `void` where you declared them in the class. Yet you don't specify a return type in the definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration return type is `void`.
`void translation(float tX, float tY, float tZ);`
 ^^^^

But your definition does not have a type.
`void Object3D::translation(float tX, float tY, float tZ)`
 ^^^^ is missing

---

When an explicit return type is missing, `int` is assumed by some compilers producing that error.

e.g. VS2019 error:
`error C4430:  missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int`

Comment: _"When an explicit type is missing, `int` is assumed."_ That is not true in C++. See Appendix C.1.6, "Banning implicit int" in the standard.

Comment: oops... I began to describe files in different files recently, so I forgot about this rule! Thank you and all who spent time on me!

Answer (score 2):

All of the definitions in `3DObjectDescription.cpp` are missing return types in their signatures.

Simply update their signatures to include the `void` return type. The definition for `Object3D::translation` should read

```
void Object3D::translation(float tX, float tY, float tZ)
{
    vertexes = nc::dot(vertexes, translate(tX, tY, tZ));
}
```

Likewise for the rest.

---

The reason that your compiler is complaining about mismatched signatures instead of indicating a syntax error is because your compiler is implicitly assuming a return type of `int` when none is specified. This is a holdover from C. However, this idiosyncrasy [was removed in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331148/does-c-allow-default-return-types-for-functions), so your compiler is exhibiting non-standard behavior by attempting to compile it.